# Unable to set distinct patterns for each variable using ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpattern

I would like to set distinct patterns for my box and whisker plot variables.

I have tried using scale_pattern_manual() but it is not setting distinct patterns for each variable and is setting a stripe pattern to all variables.

```
DF2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(c(A1, A2, A3), c(B1, B2, B3)),
  y = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 15),
  z = rep(rep(1:3, each=5), 2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
cols <- rainbow(3, s = 0.5)
boxplot(x ~ z + y, data = DF2,
        at = c(1:3, 5:7), col = cols,
        names = c("", "A", "", "", "B", ""), xaxs = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF2, aes(y, x, fill=factor(z))) +
  geom_boxplot_pattern() + scale_pattern_manual(values = c("wave","stripe","crosshatch"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thanks for accompanying your question with a reproducible example.  Will you see if you can run it in a *new* R session.  I think it has a few problems such as (a) on line 2, the values like `A1` should be `"A1"` and (b) you're missing at least one `library()` call to ggpattern.

Comment: To have different patterns you have to map on the `pattern` aes, i.e. try `aes(..., pattern = factor(z))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close, but the variables were mapped to the wrong aesthetics.  Please check my assumptions/modifications.

- I don't think `x` needs to be passed to ggplot at all.
- `z` is the only quantitative variable, so it seems like your outcome variable (so I mapped it to the *y* aesthetic).
- `y` has the values of "A" and "B", which should have different patterns
- The `y` factor has only two levels, so the crosshatch pattern is never used.

```r
DF2 <- data.frame(
  x = c(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), c("B1", "B2", "B3")),
  y = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 15),
  z = rep(rep(1:3, each=5), 2)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
ggplot(DF2, aes(x = 1, y = z, fill = factor(y), pattern = factor(y))) +
  geom_boxplot_pattern() + ggplot(DF2, aes(x = 1, y = z, fill = factor(y), pattern = factor(y))) +
  geom_boxplot_pattern() + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c("A" = "none", "B" = "stripe", "C" = "crosshatch"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked! Is there a way to make one variable a solid color and another just stripes?

Comment: Glad that meets your needs --see the edit.  Set the pattern to "none".  Don't forget to mark it as answered and then upvote any answers that you find helped.